# Changing Frames in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, frames

I have been teaching some basic programming to a family friend's daughter. We created a nice basic text adventure game in Python which works exactly as it should. However, she really wants to see it graphically and so I've tried to implement this using my extremely basic knowledge of Tkinter. Each chapter is just copied and pasted from the previous one with the button labels and links, text box contents and image references changed. I have placed each individual screen in to a separate function which is being called by clicking on a button on the previous screen. However, my issue is that, instead of replacing the screen with the new one, they are just going on top of each other. So chapter two's images, buttons and text is just being placed below chapter one's.

I can't figure out a way of killing the previous frames and widgets and replacing them with the new ones. I have tried to kill them several ways but it's either doing nothing, or killing the entire program. I've also tried using the same names for the buttons in each function but because they're local that doesn't really make a difference.

Although I realise it's inefficient, I want to try and stay away from using objects if possible because it will be extremely difficult to explain to her.

Is there any way I can do this by tweaking the structure I have created or can I only do it by using complex classes and objects? Keep in mind that this code is never going to be reused, so it doesn't matter how much of a mess it is in the background.

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

def intro():


  topFrame = Frame(root)
  topFrame.pack()
  bottomFrame = Frame(root)
  bottomFrame.pack(side = BOTTOM)

  photo = PhotoImage(file="hh.gif")
  label = Label(root, image=photo)
  label.pack(side = TOP)

  t = Text(wrap=WORD, height = 10)
  t.insert(INSERT, "This is the first screen")
  t.insert(END, "")
  t.pack()

  # button 1 here should take us to the second screen
  button1 = Button(bottomFrame, text="Option 1", fg="black", command=chapter2)
  button2 = Button(bottomFrame, text="Option 2", fg="black")
  button3 = Button(bottomFrame, text="Option 3", fg="black")

  button1.pack(side = LEFT)
  button2.pack(side = LEFT)
  button3.pack(side = LEFT)

  root.mainloop()


def chapter2():


  topFrame = Frame(root)
  topFrame.pack()
  bottomFrame = Frame(root)
  bottomFrame.pack(side = BOTTOM)

  photo1 = PhotoImage(file="hh2.gif")
  label1 = Label(root, image=photo1)
  label1.pack(side = TOP)

  t1 = Text(wrap=WORD)
  t1.insert(INSERT, "This is the second screen")
  t1.insert(END, "")
  t1.pack()

  button4 = Button(bottomFrame, text="this", fg="black")
  button5 = Button(bottomFrame, text="that", fg="black")
  button6 = Button(bottomFrame, text="the other", fg="black")

  button4.pack(side = LEFT)
  button5.pack(side = LEFT)
  button6.pack(side = LEFT)

  root.mainloop()

  intro()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening in your code is that you're creating new text fields and labels without removing the old ones.

To delete the old text/label widgets, use `pack_forget()`, in your case, `t.pack_forget()`, `label.pack_forget()`, `button1.pack_forget()`, `button2.pack_forget()`, and `button3.pack_forget()`. What `pack_forget()` does is romoving a widget from the window, like the reverse of `pack()`. So, to add this in your code, simply change line 24:

```
button1 = Button(bottomFrame, text="Option 1", fg="black", command=chapter2
```

to

```
button1 = Button(bottomFrame, text="Option 1", fg="black", command=lambda: (t.pack_forget(), label.pack_forget(), button1.pack_forget(),  button2.pack_forget(), button3.pack_forget(), chapter2()))
```

(**note** that in chapter two, you would use `t1.pack_forget()`, `label1.pack_forget()`, `button4/5/6.pack_forget()` and **not** `t/label/button1/2/3.pack_forget()`)

**You also** have to keep a reference to your photo on your label, you can do this by adding `label.image = photo` between `label = Label(topFrame, image=photo)` and `label.pack(side=TOP)` Also, see [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) page.
**Entier Edited code:**

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

def intro():

  topFrame = Frame(root)
  topFrame.pack()
  bottomFrame = Frame(root)
  bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

  photo = PhotoImage(file="hh.gif")
  label = Label(root, image=photo)
  label.image = photo # keep a reference!
  label.pack(side=TOP)

  t = Text(wrap=WORD, height=10)
  t.insert(INSERT, "This is the first screen")
  t.insert(END, "")
  t.pack()

  # button 1 here should take us to the second screen
  button1 = Button(bottomFrame, text="Option 1", fg="black", command=lambda: (t.pack_forget(), label.pack_forget(), button1.pack_forget(), button2.pack_forget(), button3.pack_forget(), chapter2()))
  button2 = Button(bottomFrame, text="Option 2", fg="black")
  button3 = Button(bottomFrame, text="Option 3", fg="black")

  button1.pack(side=LEFT)
  button2.pack(side=LEFT)
  button3.pack(side=LEFT)

def chapter2():

  topFrame = Frame(root)
  topFrame.pack()
  bottomFrame = Frame(root)
  bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

  photo1 = PhotoImage(file="hh2.gif")
  label1 = Label(root, image=photo1)
  label.image = photo # keep a reference!
  label1.pack(side=TOP)

  t1 = Text(wrap=WORD)
  t1.insert(INSERT, "This is the second screen")
  t1.insert(END, "")
  t1.pack()

  button4 = Button(bottomFrame, text="this", fg="black")
  button5 = Button(bottomFrame, text="that", fg="black")
  button6 = Button(bottomFrame, text="the other", fg="black")

  button4.pack(side=LEFT)
  button5.pack(side=LEFT)
  button6.pack(side=LEFT)

intro()

root.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps, if it doesn't, please comment and I'll try to find another solution :)

Also, if you're wondering what lambda is (Part of the edited code), simply google "python lambda".

Comment: you can also remove the  `root.mainloop()` in each function, and add only one after `intro()`

Comment: @PRMoureu That might work... sorry, didn't quite understand you, but it might work :)

Comment: tkinter needs only one main loop in this case, at the end, after `intro()` .

Comment: @PRMoureu Oh, gotcha. yes, that's true, I thought you meant something completely different, thanks! Should I edit it or should you make an edit request? (since you told me)

Comment: please go on ! it's yours

Comment: @PRMoureu Well then, Thanks again!

Comment: @PRMoureu: Not `in this case` but always. Tkinter needs exactly one intance of `Tk()` and only one use of `mainloop()`

Comment: Strangely though, since adding in the topFrame reference in the image part, the images no longer appear. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, with both versions suggested here by Mocqoro and Nelson my images are no longer showing.

Comment: @user1480135 I did some research and found a page saying "You must keep a reference to the image object in your Python program, either by storing it in a global variable or by attaching it to another object." You can do this by adding `label.image = photo` between `label = Label(topFrame, image=photo)` and `label.pack(side=TOP)` I'll edit my answer to show it to you in more detail.

Comment: @user1480135 I also recommend you using Nelsons code

Comment: @user1480135 did it work when you added `label.image = photo` in your code?

Answer (score 2):

To build on mocqoro's answer, I will suggest you put each chapter in a Frame. This way, when you want to move to the next chapter, you can just `pack_forget` or `destroy` (`pack_forget` is good for if you want to re-pack a widget later, `destroy` deletes the widget completely) the chapter's Frame instead of each individual widget:

```
from tkinter import *

def intro():
    chapterFrame = Frame(root) 
    chapterFrame.pack()

    topFrame = Frame(chapterFrame) # top and bottom frames are children of chapterFrame
    topFrame.pack()

    photo = PhotoImage(file="hh.gif")
    label = Label(topFrame, image=photo)
    label.image = photo
    label.pack(side=TOP)

    t = Text(topFrame, wrap=WORD, height=10)
    t.insert(INSERT, "This is the first screen")
    t.pack()

    bottomFrame = Frame(chapterFrame)
    bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    # button 1 here should take us to the second screen
    # button1 deletes the entire chapter and calls chapter2
    button1 = Button(bottomFrame, text="Option 1", fg="black", command=lambda: (chapterFrame.destroy(), chapter2()))
    button2 = Button(bottomFrame, text="Option 2", fg="black")
    button3 = Button(bottomFrame, text="Option 3", fg="black")

    button1.pack(side=LEFT)
    button2.pack(side=LEFT)
    button3.pack(side=LEFT)

def chapter2():
    chapterFrame = Frame(root)
    chapterFrame.pack()

    topFrame = Frame(chapterFrame)
    topFrame.pack()

    photo1 = PhotoImage(file="hh2.gif")
    label1 = Label(topFrame, image=photo1)
    label1.image = photo1
    label1.pack(side = TOP)

    t1 = Text(topFrame, wrap=WORD)
    t1.insert(INSERT, "This is the second screen")
    t1.pack()

    bottomFrame = Frame(chapterFrame)
    bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    button4 = Button(bottomFrame, text="this", fg="black")
    # button5 loops back to intro
    button5 = Button(bottomFrame, text="that", fg="black", command=lambda: (chapterFrame.destroy(), intro()))
    button6 = Button(bottomFrame, text="the other", fg="black")

    button4.pack(side=LEFT)
    button5.pack(side=LEFT)
    button6.pack(side=LEFT)

root = Tk()
intro()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much for your help. My images no longer seem to be appearing though. Any ideas?

Comment: The only difference I see is that the Label's parent is `topFrame` instead of `root`. Try changing that. If that doesn't work, it could be a typo or some other error in my editing. I would suggest undo-ing until the images work, then fix 1 line at a time and run it until the images don't show up.

Comment: @mocqoro thank you for the edit. It was not in the code I copied from, so I left that out. Do you happen to know why that extra line is required? It seems redundant but always breaks the code without it.

Comment: @Nelson I don't know why, it seems very unpythonic, at least for me. You can read about it here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm

Comment: @mocqoro Trust me, I've looked over that page so many times trying to figure out why

Comment: @Nelson Ok, well then, it says "Note: When a PhotoImage object is garbage-collected by Python (e.g. when you return from a function which stored an image in a local variable), the image is cleared even if it’s being displayed by a Tkinter widget.

To avoid this, the program must keep an extra reference to the image object. A simple way to do this is to assign the image to a widget attribute, like this:

`label = Label(image=photo)   
label.image = photo # keep a reference!   
label.pack()`"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148861/discussion-between-nelson-and-mocqoro).

Comment: @user1480135 The line in mocqoro's answer that has the comment "keep a reference!" next to it needs to be added to your code to display the images